# how do print the full array when using np.testing with 2D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using assertions like `np.testing.assert_all_equal` to check whether arrays are as expected. However, for 2D arrays I only see up to 3 elements of axis 0. e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.expand_dims(np.arange(10), 1)
x2 = np.expand_dims(np.arange(10), 1)
x2[8] = 0

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(x1, x2)
```

This results in:

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals

Mismatched elements: 1 / 10 (10%)
Max absolute difference: 8
Max relative difference: 0.
 x: array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],...
 y: array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],...
```

This is less than helpful since I can't see where the mismatch is. I've tried using `np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=10)` to no avail.

How can I set it up so that my asserts print the full contents of the arrays on failure?

Comment: I guess you can't do anything about it as the maximum of 3 elements [is hard-coded](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c8dd91b633798a4082f255784dec483b08351f58/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L268-L270)

Comment: oh dang. Nice find though, thanks! Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't do anything about it as the maximum of 3 elements [is hard-coded](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c8dd91b633798a4082f255784dec483b08351f58/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L268-L270) in `numpy.testing._private.utils.build_err_msg`:

```
        if r.count('\n') > 3:
            r = '\n'.join(r.splitlines()[:3])
            r += '...'
```

(unless you make your own `build_err_msg` based on numpy's and redefine `np.testing._private.utils.build_err_msg = my_build_err_msg`)